# unable to send e-mail using my function

Tags: php, sendmail

I am facing e-mail sending problem.

e-mail does not send through my e-mail function.

My code is given below:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from",$_POST['email']);
$to      = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$from    = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
mail($to,$subject,$message,$from);
```

Comment: Do you have a mail server setup locally?

Comment: Enable error logs and see what is the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your SMTP mail server and mention those details in php.ini before executing your script. For further info, please check http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/23.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have to set proper header,
you have used `$from` for header section of mail.

change its value as

```
$from= 'From: '.$_POST['email']. "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

or you can use below solution.

Use `PHPMailer` API for sending mail. all are inbuilt there.
download complete code form below link
[PHPMailer API](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

goodluck